# ipad every time launch sencha touch 2 web app from home screen application reload from beginning

Tags: ios, ipad, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a web application based on **sencha touch 2 framework**.
simply when adding home screen shortcut in **iPad** and open the application each time application ***restart from beginning*** and iPad didn't save the state of current page.

The Cache size of my application about 2MB.

Can I save state of my application like **Safari ?**

Answer (score 1):

To go offline you should configure app cache manifest and specify the resources that are available online or offline.

Read the following 
http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline/
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_html_manifest.asp

Comment: Already I configure cache manifest and cache size is about 2MB.

Comment: So whats the problem ? What do you mean under 'save state' ?

Comment: Save state: in full screen mode when you pass login view and working in application, if you open another application like music player in iPad and return to my application the application refresh from beginning then return to login view.

Comment: kitchen Sink example from Sencha has same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring routes for your controller action. That way the state is persisted through the url when you switch back.

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap the web application to the native one using cordova (formerly phonegap) package.

Comment: I know that, but I prefer anyone to use the application directly.